# Changing the Pin of a Virtual SmartCard in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10, smartcard

In our environment we need a virtual smart card for VPN authentication under Windows 10 and we need to create a little tool for the users to change the pin of the virtual smart cards.
I've downloaded the [Smart card sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Smart-card-sample-c7d342e0) to see how to create a virtual smart card and change it's pin. But I'm having trouble with running the code.

My first problem is, that I'm getting a 'The request requires elevation' Exception on calling the method `RequestVirtualSmartCardCreationAsync`. I'm using the default parameters defined in the project. I tried to log-in as an Admin and Visual Studio is also started as Administrator. I also made sure that the 'Shared User Certificates' option is checked under Capabilities in the appxmanifest.

Next I tried to create a virtual smart card with the tpmsvcmgr.exe command line tool. The command line was: `tpmvscmgr.exe create /name myVSC /pin prompt /adminkey default /generate`
I made sure that the virtual smart card was generated successfully by finding it in the device manager under Smartcard-Readers.
Next I modified the code from the sample by setting the `SmartCardReaderDeviceId` in the `ValidateTPMSmartCard()` method just before the check whether the `string` is empty.
I tried different values for this variable but I'm still getting Exceptions in the `GetSmartCard()` method on `SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync` during code execution. Here are the values that I tried with the according Exceptions that I get:

```
//NO_SUCH_DEVICE_INTERFACE
SmartCardReaderDeviceId = "ROOT\\SMARTCARDREADER\\0000";
//NO_SUCH_DEVICE_INTERFACE
SmartCardReaderDeviceId = "\\ROOT\\SMARTCARDREADER\\0000";
//NO_SUCH_DEVICE_INTERFACE
SmartCardReaderDeviceId = "\\\\?\\ROOT#SMARTCARDREADER#0000";
//REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
SmartCardReaderDeviceId = "\\\\?\\ROOT#SMARTCARDREADER#0000#{50dd5230-ba8a-11d1-bf5d-0000f805f530}";
//NO_SUCH_DEVICE_INTERFACE
SmartCardReaderDeviceId = "50dd5230-ba8a-11d1-bf5d-0000f805f530}";
```

Does anyone know either how to get this SDK sample to work or how to change the PIN of a virtual smart card programatically?

I'm running this Project under Windows 10.0.10586 with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on a Surface Pro 4.